# How to recover a 12TB RAID 10 array that's showing up as two uninitialized 6TB drives in Windows 7?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, ssd, raid, intel-rst

I have an ASUS Maximus VI Formula motherboard which was giving me trouble with it's USB 3.0 hub (Intel) so as part of the trouble shooting process I upgraded the BIOS to the latest. Big mistake, should have gone with my first idea of deleting the hub in Windows and reloading the drivers...

I had a RAID 0 array of two 256GB SSDs and a RAID 10 array of four 3TB HDDs. When the BIOS was upgraded it decided to reset and it ended up failing the RAID 0 array because it tried to startup in SATA mode instead of RAID mode. I spent half the day trying to recover the RAID 0 partition using TestDisk, but it didn't work, so I reloaded the OS and tried to see if I can recover something using Recuva. After Recuva scanned the drive, I saw the files I was going to try to recover but they were damaged by the installation of the ever useful hybernation file. So, I gave up, and I'm OK with it because I had planned to reload the OS eventually with a GPT partition so I didn't keep a whole lot on that drive.

What I found next is what has me worried though. The RAID 10 array was not showing up, but instead I was seeing two inaccessible 6TB drives. The RAID 10 array was never damaged by the BIOS reset nor did I touch it with TestDisk, but alas, it is now in an unusable state.

I presume that the data is still on the drives, I just need a way to access it and dump it to some external drives and rebuild the array. I know I only used 1/3 of the capacity of the drive, so ~2TB, probably less.

So, my question is, how can I go about recovering the data? I presume since it's striping first, then mirroring, the task is not that easy since all the files are split in half between the two stripes? Am I wrong? Am I misunderstanding the writing process?

Can I initialize the two drives as GPT partitions within Windows (NOT the RAID controller) and gain access to the files or will the striping process make that moot?

I look forward to any recommendations.

Comment: Obligatory "RAID is not backup" reminder.

Comment: I have reassembled a raid0 after a similar breakage of the raid , I used the same stripe size and the exact same configuration. But I had it written down so I could reassemble it the same way it was assembled.  (intel bios said "creating the array would wipe out the data", it did not wipe it for me) You have 2 teams of drives with half the data (the 0 part of the 10) Somehow get at least one set reassembled first, best would be the same way same stuff that assembled it to begin with.  that is all i can say.

Comment: Well, thinking about it, I think what I'm seeing is the two RAID 0 arrays, since they're showing up as 6TB. One is the primary and the other is the mirror. So, if I'm correct, I think I can just GPT initialize one and have full access to everything. I haven't braved doing that yet though.